# Send a POST request to an endpoint with C# and HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, json, rest, post

It is no problem for me to send a GET-Request to an endpoint with the following code (of course with the GET-Method), but I am not able to do a POST-Request. Can somebody explain, what I have to do in order to be able to POST the exemplary JSON-Body?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


namespace RestTesting

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string url;
            url = "https://server.APIEndpoint/REST/";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.KeepAlive = true;

            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            Console.WriteLine("Request: {0} \"{1}\" ...", request.Method, request.RequestUri);
            Console.WriteLine(request.Headers);
            Console.WriteLine(request.ContentLength);

            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Response: HTTP/{0} {1} ({1:d})\n", response.ProtocolVersion, response.StatusCode));

                Console.WriteLine(response.Headers);
                string responseText;

                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                Console.WriteLine(response.ContentType);

                if (response.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json"))
                {
                    JObject json = (JObject)JObject.Parse(responseText);
                    Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());
                }

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(err);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

And here is a JSON-Body:

```
{
"reference": "Test", 
"info": "additionalInfo", 
"ID": null, 
"confidential": false,
}
```

The issue is: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at RestTesting.Program.Main(String[] args)

That error occurs when I try to post the JSON-Body like below (after the WebRequest.Create Method):

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string data = @"{
        "reference": "Test", 
        "info": "additionalInfo", 
        "ID": null, 
        "confidential": false,  
    }";
    streamWriter.Write(data);
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is the issue?  Are you getting error exception what is it?  Is your code not compiling?  Clearly you are doing a post.

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to mention the issue:

System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at RestTesting.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: That error occurs when I try to post the JSON-Body like below (after the WebRequest.Create Method): 

`using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
 {
  string data = @"{
  "reference": "Test", 
  "info": "additionalInfo", 
  "ID": null, 
  "confidential": false, 
 }";
 streamWriter.Write(data);
}`

Comment: First off if you can paste the messages like this in the question and not comments makes it easier to understand.  Second the issue is not your post require but the URL you are posting to does not exist.  You need to check the api/page endpoint and confirm it exists.

Comment: Thanks, edits done in the initial post. I will try.

Comment: @AliK: I changed the URL of the endpoint. Now i get a "Bad Request"-Error (400). Does that automatically mean, that the URL ist correct, but the request not?

Comment: Correct means there is something there but its not reading what your sending.

Comment: create a class object for your request body, then serialize it using Json.NET, and write the serialized object to the request stream, ensure you provide the correct `Encoding` for the stream writer as well. This would ensure you send a valid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I just forgot a comma in my code in the JSON-Body.